# Non-orthogonal basis satisfying the Bessel's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

As we know that

> If $H$ is a Hilbe$\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal sequence then for all $x\in H$ 
>   $$\|x\|^2\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2$$ and the infinite sum converges to $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle x,e_k \rangle e_k. $$

I was thinking for that if we don't  have an orthonormal basis then can we give an example of such sequence which satisfies $\|x\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|
\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\ \ $    for all $x\in H$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'don't have an orthonormal basis'? Do you mean any sequence or a Schauder basis that is not orthornomal?

Comment: Any sequence or a Schauder basis anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Parseval equality, then the $e_n$ are orthogonal because
$$
         \|e_n\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle e_n,e_k\rangle|^2=\|e_n\|^2+\sum_{k\ne n}|\langle e_n,e_k\rangle|^2.
$$